# Google web fonts and IE9

Tags: cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, google-webfonts

I'm developing a landing page that uses embedded Google web fonts. When I test the page in IE9 locally, it renders in IE9 Compatibility View and IE7 document mode by default – but it looks fine (I believe it does this because local files are considered "intranet" and IE9 automatically renders those in compatibility view).

However, when I then manually switch the browser and document modes to IE9 – which is how the page would render when actually served – the Google web fonts no longer work.

Google web fonts are supposed to work on IE9, so what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a cross-domain issue or something when viewing the page locally. The same exact page, once uploaded to my server, renders in IE9 standards mode by default and the Google fonts work fine.